# vars(A()) returns a blank dict

Tags: python

Suppose the quick `class` example:

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")
    def stop(self):
        print("stop A stop!")
    def pause(self):
        raise Exception("Not Implemented")
```

I tried to compare the attribute of class A and instance A()

```
In [67]: dir(A) == dir(A())
Out[67]: True
```

However, when test with `vars`

```
In [68]: vars(A) == vars(A())
Out[68]: False

In [73]: A.__dict__
Out[73]: 
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'go': <function __main__.A.go(self)>,
              'stop': <function __main__.A.stop(self)>,
              'pause': <function __main__.A.pause(self)>,
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})

In [74]: A().__dict__
Out[74]: {}
```

It's obvious that `go`, `stop` and `pause` are of instance methods,

> vars([object])
>   Return the **dict** attribute for a module, class, **instance**, or any other object with a **dict** attribute.

Additionally, `vars` could return an instance attributes.

What's the reason the `A().__dict__` return a blank dict.

Comment: ... Because nothing has been assigned to instance attributes.

Comment: Do you understand what `A()` means? It creates an `A` instance. There's no code in `__init__` that adds instance variables to such an instance. You're not doing it manually anywhere. So it has no instance variables.

Comment: If you're wondering why `dir` acts differently, look at its help: `its attributes, its class's attributes, and recursively the attributes of its class's base classes`. That's obviously different than just the attributes in its `__dict__`.

Comment: but I think it inherit `__init__` from `object` or why we can utilize `def go(self)`, pass `self` in go() @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @hero.hacker because *methods belong to the class, not the instance*. Just forget about `dir`, dir is for debugging in the REPL for convenience.

Comment: so it's `def go(cls):
        print("go A go!")` ty @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @hero.hacker what? What are you trying to say? The first argument to a method get's passed *an instance* if it is called through an instance, this happens "magically", although it isn't magic, under the hood, function objects are descriptors.

Comment: I mean `go` is class method, but `self` (the shadow of instance) is passed in rather than cls. so I assume it should be `go(cls)` instead of `go(self)` here @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @hero.hacker no it is **not a classmethod**. And it doesn't matter what you name the first parameter of a method, you can name it `banana` if you want. The point is that it get's passed the instance implicitly. And `self` isn't a "shadow" if an instance. It is simply a normal parameter like any other, it's just that function descriptors pass the instance to the first positional argument.

Comment: em, confused here, `methods belong to the class` but not a `classmethod` @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @hero.hacker yes, you are confused. **all methods** belong to the class. Classmethods, instance methods, and static methods. You have only dealt with normal instance methods here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the function `vars(obj)` returns attributes in `obj.__dict__`.

On the other hand, calling `dir(obj)` attempts to retrieve the list of valid attributes for `obj`, attributes you could access with `getattr`.

Methods defined in the class body are attributes of the class, not of its instances. This means they are stored in `A.__dict__`.

```
class A:
    def bar(self):
        pass

print(A.__dict__)  # { ..., 'bar': <function Foo.bar at 0x000001D38ED218C8>, ... }
print(A().__dict__) # {}
```

Although, if you were to set an attribute on an instance, either manually or in the `__init__` method, then it would be returned by `vars`.

```
foo = A()
foo.baz = 'Python'

print(foo.__dict__) # {'baz': 'Python'}
print(vars(foo)) # {'baz': 'Python'}
```

Answer (score 0):

A is class and A() is an instance. So when you do A.**dict** it returns the class definition as in structure but when you do A().**dict** it returns the instance values attributes assigned